# How do I use a jquery method on a variable when the same method exists in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

Specifically, I want to call the .which function on a character without having to discriminate browser types by using the `jQuery` .which method, which I am told normalizes for browser differences.  However, the innate javascript method also exists, so if I called character.which, I would get the javascript .which keycode instead of the jquery one (presumably).  Do I use `$(character)`.which or `$("character")`.which or will this not work at all? What's the syntax?

Comment: From the little research I just did, it appears that .which is only in jQuery, it isn't in vanilla JavaScript. And the documentation says to just use it like `event.which`. https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery is bit different in terms of Syntax as if you are using jQuery the process is:

$("ELEMENT_TO_BE_PROCESSED").FUNCTION/OBJECT;